# Regex match for colon separated string with double quotes and GUID using C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to find a regex match for possible app IDs such as:

```
"AppId": "12764ddf-2746-4293-8f63-b79fdc913dca"
"appid": "12764ddf-2746-4293-8f63-b79fdc913dca"
```

Currently, my regex looks like this, but the quotation marks around app ID
are giving compilation errors. I also tried using `\"`, but that also does not work:

```
Regex appIdRegex = new Regex(@"("appid")"(\s*):(\s*)^[{(]?[0-9A-F]{8}[-]?(?:[0-9A-F]{4}[-]?){3}[0-9A-F]{12}[)}]?$",
                RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: It seems like your data might be JSON. Why not use a JSON parser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using @ string, you need to escape " using "".

```
Regex appIdRegex = new Regex(@"\""appid\""\s*:\s*\""([0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12})\""$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```